# What does count as taking damage?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I was wondering about the rules behind the "*no damage*" achievements. I've found these on the older Binding of Isaac [Wikia's page](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/No_Damage_Achievement_Guide).

> What counts as "taking damage?"
>
> - Getting hit by an enemy, enemy projectile, bomb
> - Purchasing an item from the Devil Room.
> - Spike door in the Curse Room.
>
> What doesn't count as "taking damage?"
>
> - Using the Blood Donation Machine or IV bag.
> - Damage taken from the Devil Beggar.
> - The "Bad Trip" or the "Health Down" pill effects.
> - The Razor Blade and Blood Rights items.
> - Using a "Health up!" pill.
> - Taking damage while under the effect of Holy Mantle

I know that **Holy Mantle** is a new item, so this seems to be an updated list, but it's on the old wikia, so the question is: is this list reliable for *Rebirth* too?
I need to know if *Devil Deals* still count as damage taken.

Comment: Why would Devil Deals count as damage taken?  They don't take away health, they take away your actual heart containers.

Comment: Because in the previous BoI they did, so it's a legitimate doubt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Losing or gaining health (upgrades / downgrades) isn't seen as damage, for example:

- Health up / down pill
- Devil deal
- Black market deal
- Guppy's paw (converts red hearts into soul hearts)

Stuff that deals damage:

- Bad trip pil
- Items that reduces / damages health (IV bag, blood rights)
- Blood banks
- Enemy contact / attacks / projectiles (not all enemies have contact damage)
- (bomb) explosions (unless when you have Pyromaniac)
- Spike door to the curse room
- Devil beggar

Items that help you in a run:

- Holy mantle (automatically blocks the first damage taken)
- Infamy (Can block projectiles on the side Isaac is facing)
- Lost Contact (Block enemy projectiles with your own projectiles)
- Gnawed Leaf (enemies cannot damage you when you're in statue form)

[Source: experienced it myself: clearing parts of the game without receiving damage](http://steamcommunity.com/id/masterjoost/stats/appid/250900/achievements)

### Achievements:

**Basement Boy**

> Beat basement without taking damage.

**Spelunker Boy**

> Beat caves without taking damage.

**Dark Boy**

> Beat depths without taking damage.

**Mama's Boy**

> Beat womb without taking damage.

**Dead Boy**

> Beat Chest or Dark Room without taking damage.

### Synergies:

Lost Contact

- Piercing tears (tears are not destroyed on blocking enemy projectiles)
- Brimstone / Technology (laser will destroy all tears in it's path)
- The Ludovico Technique (floating tear cannot be destroyed, but will destroy projectiles)
- Mom's knife (Knife cannot be destroyed, but will destroy projectiles)

Gnawed Leaf

- Midas touch (when enemies hit you, they are turned into gold statues)
- E coli (when enemies hit you, they are turned into poop)
- The virus (when enemies hit you, they are poisoned)
- Gemini (Gemini will auto attack near enemies)
- Ball of bandages / cube of meat (damages enemies near / around you)
- Sacrificial Dagger (damages enemies near / around you)
- Daddy Longlegs (foot stomps enemies automatically)
- Leech (The leech will automatically attack and chase enemy around the room)
- Lil' Haunt (Lil' Haunt will automatically attack and chase enemy around the room)
- Demon Baby (Demon Baby will automatically attack enemies in range)

Comment: Best Answer is tested answer :D

Comment: The first part of your answer is enough to me. I've already done each no damage achievements, I just asked for curiosity :) Anyway the best Synergy is Gnawed Leaf + Ludovico Technique + Brimstone!

Answer (score 3):

According to [GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/692703-the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth/70589083), it seems that in *Rebirth* Devil Deals no longer count as damage taken, unlike the original *Binding of Isaac*.